# Proof verification for a theorem about a harmonic function on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, harmonic-functions

I would like to prove the following result

[image]

I will be quoting the previous result and its proof :

[image]

**Proof for Theorem 1.4** Suppose $\exists (a,b)\in D(0,1)$ such that $u(a,b)>0$. Let
\begin{align*}
X = \left\{z: |z|\leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad z\neq z_0  \right\}
\end{align*}
If $u$ has a maximum in $D(0,1)$, then apply the same argument as in the proof of the above theorem. Else consider $C_{R}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
C_{R}=\left(D(0,1) \cup \partial D(0,1)\right) \setminus D(z_0,R)
\end{align*}
illustrated as

[image]

By construction $u$ achieves its minimum and maximum on the boundary $\partial C_{R}$. Let
\begin{align*}
M= \sup \left\{\max_{C_{R}}u  \mid 0<R<1 \right\}
\end{align*}
which exists as $u$ is bounded and because the set is non empty. By assumption $u$ can not achieve $M$ on  $X$.

Now given $\epsilon>0$, define
\begin{align*}
T=\left\{\max_{C_{R}}u \mid  0<R<\epsilon \right\}
\end{align*}
By construction
\begin{align*}
M=\sup T.
\end{align*}
By definition, given $\delta >0$, there exists $\tau $ with  $0<\tau<\epsilon$ such that
\begin{align*}
\max_{C_{\tau }}u &  > \sup T + \delta  \\ 
 &  = M +\delta 
\end{align*}
by applying the definition of supremum of $T$.
Now we use continuity. For any point $z_1 $ on the boundary of the open disc, except for $z_0$, we have that given $A>0$ , there exists $B>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|z-z_1 |<B \implies  |u(z)-u(z_1 )|<A
\end{align*}
By hypothesis, the maximum on $C_{\tau }$ lies on the semi circle. Let $z_2$ be that point. Then let $z_3$ be one of the points where the circle and semi circle intersect. Then
\begin{align*}
|z_3-z_2|<2\tau
\end{align*}
geometrically as they lie on the same circle of radius $\tau $. Take $A<M$. Now set $\epsilon<\frac{B}{2}$, so $\tau<\frac{B}{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
|z_3 -z_2|<B 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
|u(z_3)-u(z_2)|&  = |u(z_2)| \\ 
 &  > M +\delta  > A
\end{align*}
which contradicts the continuity.

**Question:** Does my proof hold?

Comment: Now posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426027/proof-verification-for-a-theorem-about-a-harmonic-function-on-the-unit-disc

Comment: And has been removed because it is not for professional mathematimaticians,

Comment: Or even professional mathematicians. But in fact it has not been removed; it has been closed, which is a very different thing.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling. At this point if anyone can say a simple yes with some justification would be better than anything.